# Почему не работает? С модулем calendar

Tags: python, calendar

```
import calendar 

def is_year_leap(year) 
    calendar.isleap(year) 
    if True: 
        return True 
    else: 
        return False 
is_year_leap()
```

Comment: В целом, крайне рекомендую прочесть хотя бы вводные гайды по тому, как писать функции на питоне, про условные операторы, циклы и прочие базовые вещи, т.к. без них попросту нельзя написать ничего базового. Также при оформлении вопроса пишите подробнее, что не работает, в таких вопросах в процессе поиска на него ответа сами сможетеразобраться, в чем была проблема. В Вашем случае все ошибки можно исправить вручную, просто посмотрев на ошибку, которую сгенерировал интерпритатор. Как вариант, можете начать с этого [сайта](https://www.w3schools.com/python/default.asp), для первого знакомства хватит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, после строки `def is_year_leap(year)` пропущено двоеточие, то есть правильно:

`def is_year_leap(year) :`

Также дальнейший блок, в котором при значении `True` Вы возвращаете `True`, а в противном случае `False`, не имеет смысла, т.к. всегда будет возвращено `True`.

Ну и последнее, это то, что Вы вызвали функцию `is_year_leap` без параметра.

Если я правильно понял, Вы хотели получить такой код в результате:

```
import calendar


def is_year_leap(year):
    if calendar.isleap(year):
        return True
    else:
        return False


is_year_leap(2019)
```

Comment: Все это сокращается в `return calendar.isleap(year)`. Хоть и непонятно, зачем писать отдельную функцию, которая делает то же самое, что делает единственная функция внутри ее.

Comment: @Эникейщик, полагаю, что автор вопроса только начал учить язык и для него так удобнее/нагляднее/etc. Но с Вашим комментарием, конечно же, тоже согласен.